# Ruby - Passing binding variables in SQL execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I want to try to access a MySQL database:

```
require 'rubygems'
require "dbi"

class DBConnection
  attr_accessor :dbh
  #Connect to db 
  def connect?(driver_url,user,pass)
    begin
      @dbh = DBI.connect(driver_url, user,pass);
      return true
    rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
        puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
        @dbh.rollback
        return false
    ensure
      @dbh.disconnect if !dbh
    end
  end

  def execute_customize(query,params)
    stm = @dbh.prepare(query)
    if( (params != nil) && !(params.empty?) )
       stm.execute(params)
    else
      stm.execute
    end
    header = false
    stm.fetch do |row|
      if (!header)
          puts("ID   Name")
          header = true
      end
       puts("#{row[0]}   #{row[1]}")
    end
  end
end

db = DBConnection.new
db.connect?("DBI:Mysql:test:localhost", "root", "123456")
db.execute_customize("SELECT * FROM test.employee WHERE name = ? OR name = ? ",*["John","Terry"])
```

But the above returns the following error:

```
in `execute_customize': wrong number of arguments (3 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

But the execution is successful with:

```
dbh.execute_customize("SELECT * FROM test.employee WHERE name = ?",*["John"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
Demo data from employee table :
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | John  |
|    2 | Terry |
|    3 | Vidal |
|    4 | CR7   |
|    5 | M10   |
|    6 | R10   |
|    7 | F4    |
+------+-------+
```

// Update : Your comment almost told me using IN in query, but if with other query like :

```
SELECT * FROM test.employee WHERE name = ? and id > ?
```

I still need a way to passing seperate paramer to every "?" character

Comment: `Employee.where(name: ['John', 'Terry'])`

Comment: What is `dbh`? How did you create it? The mysql2 gm doesn't seem to have an `execute` at all and the old mysql gem's `execute` doesn't work like that.

Comment: I've post full of my example ,i rewrite execute() function to execute_customize()

Answer (score 3):

You're passing three arguments instead of two.

The splat operator `*` expands the array, so its elements are treated as separate arguments.

Try

```
dbh.execute("SELECT * FROM test.employee WHERE name IN (?)", names)
```

where `names` is a comma-separated list of strings.

That should work, but you may not need to use `execute` for this.

If you're using Rails, you can just use

```
Employee.where(name: ["John","Terry"])
```

and ActiveRecord will understand what you mean.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: while the question is tagged with rails, there's nothing rails-specific in his code and you shouldn't assume he's using ActiveRecord.

Comment: Are you sure that `WHERE name IN ?` ends up like `where name in ('John', 'Terry')` rather than `where name in 'John'`?

Comment: Thanks,but i get a mysql syntax error ("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OF 'JohnTerry')...") And i wondering why my array parameter contain 2 elements but Ruby flatten it to 3 elements ??

Comment: Revised. Should work with MySQL now: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: The splat operator decomposes an array into its constituent elements, so including `*[:one, :two]` in an argument list passes two arguments instead of one.

Comment: also, the first string, `"SELECT * FROM test.employee WHERE name = ? OR name = ? "` counts as an argument.

Comment: Sorry,my code make you misunderstand about execute() function.I've post full my example .I want to create a class with customize execute() function which named with execute_customize().Please help me correct it .many thanks

Comment: @Novice The fundamental problem is still the same. jmromer is correct that the splat operator has the effect of separating out the components of the array in to individual elements when it is passed to your custom method. It ends up being the same as if you called `execute_customize(query, "John", "Terry")`, which would give you the same error. Either remove the asterisks from the method invocation, or alter the method to accept a variable number of `params`, by doing `execute_customize(query, *params)`.

Comment: @sevenseacat he prefaced his comment with "If you're using Rails," which makes no assumption whatsoever about rails.